# p5.js - get a rectangle to move left and right repeatedly (bounce)

Tags: if-statement, p5.js, bounce

I'm trying out some sample code for a bigger project, and I'm having trouble getting my rectangle to bounce between two lines.

```javascript
function draw() {
    print(frameCount)
    background(255)
    var x = 150 + frameCount;
    rect(x,200,15,15);
    line(150,0,150,400);
    line(250,0,250,400);
    if (x >= 250) {
        background(255)
        x = 350-frameCount;
        rect(x,200,15,15);
        line(250,0,250,400);
        line(150,0,150,400);
    } if (x <= 145) {
        background(255)
        x = 145 + (frameCount % 100);
        rect(x,200,15,15);
        line(250,0,250,400);
        line(150,0,150,400);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the feeling that after the first instance, it's disregarding the original if statement, which dictates a bounce to the left. I'm really not sure what's going wrong, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just want to store the current position and speed in a set of variables, and then move the rectangle based on those. Here's an example:

```javascript
var x = 0;
var speed = 1;

function draw(){
   x += speed;
   if(x < 0 || x > width){
      speed *= -1;
   }

   background(64);
   line(x, 0, x, height);
}
```

I've written a tutorial on this available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation). That's for regular Processing, but the ideas are the same in P5.js.